# VBA - Shorten repetitive formula assignment

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to shorten my very repetitive code, which has many sets of these lines:

```
.Range("AB81") = "=VLOOKUP(I65,'[" & R1 & "]" & "Investments" & "'! $B$58:$F$81," & 5 & ",0)"
.Range("AD81") = "=VLOOKUP(K65,'[" & R1 & "]" & "Investments" & "'! $B$58:$F$81," & 5 & ",0)"
.Range("AF81") = "=VLOOKUP(M65,'[" & R1 & "]" & "Investments" & "'! $B$58:$F$81," & 5 & ",0)"
.Range("AH81") = "=VLOOKUP(O65,'[" & R1 & "]" & "Investments" & "'! $B$58:$F$81," & 5 & ",0)"
.Range("AJ81") = "=VLOOKUP(Q65,'[" & R1 & "]" & "Investments" & "'! $B$58:$F$81," & 5 & ",0)"
.Range("AL81") = "=VLOOKUP(S65,'[" & R1 & "]" & "Investments" & "'! $B$58:$F$81," & 5 & ",0)"
```

The `.Range(..81)` range moves by 2 columns each time, as does the first range inside the `VLOOKUP` formula.

Comment: `OFFSET` and a loop    will do.

Comment: Perhaps a defined `range` object to both as anchor for offset, and the 58 to 81, same with the investments as a `worksheet`, easier to change if the range changes etc.

Answer (score 2):

Relative references auto-adjust when setting all formulas at once:

```
.Range("AB81,AD81,AF81,AH81,AJ81,AL81").Formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP(I65,'[" & R1 & "]" & "Investments" & "'!$B$58:$F$81," & 5 & ",0)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a For loop, with a  step size of 2 (as you are jumping 2 columns each line). Then increment the formula range and the inner range by 2 columns each time using the `Offset` command:

```
Dim ofst As Long
For ofst = 0 To 10 Step 2
    .Range("AB81").Offset(0,ofst).Formula = _ 
        "=VLOOKUP(" & .Range("I65").Offset(0,ofst).Address & ",'[" & R1 & "]" & "Investments" & "'! $B$58:$F$81," & 5 & ",0)"
Next ofst
```

Answer (score 0):

I have always been firmly opposed to writing code to insert formulas. It's like asking the mechanic to fetch a mechanic to fix the car. The following code therefore writes the result into each cell rather than the formula. But if it is the formula you must absolutely have, it could be modified using the same logic used in constructing the loop here.

```
Private Sub ShortenRepetitiveCode()

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim LookupRange As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    Set LookupRange = Worksheets(Ws.Cells(1, "R").Value & " Investments").Range("B58:F81")
    For i = 9 To 19 Step 2              ' specify columns I to S
        Ws.Cells(81, (i + 19)).Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Ws.Cells(65, i).Value, LookupRange, 5, False)
    Next i
End Sub
```